# Automatic submit of form on page load cause infinite loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

[image]i'm using a Filter in which i use the Form..When a user a land on the list page it should automatically submit the form so user can get values only he want to see. i have tried a lot of things like jquery JS and using snippet in body but none of them is working. For the following code the form keep on submitting.

```
<div class="container shop-filter">
    <div class="filter">
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart-form-data" id="city-filter" name="cit-filter">
            <select name="filter" id="select">
            <option value="all">All city</option>
                <?php 
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM tcity";
                        $connect= mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Failed To Connect.");
                        while($rows= mysqli_fetch_array($connect, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
                            <option value= "<?php echo $rows['c_id']?>" id="optin_val" <?php echo (!empty($_COOKIE['dropdown']) && $_COOKIE['dropdown'] == $rows['c_id'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo $rows['city_nm'];?></option>
                        <?php }
                    ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submitt" id="submitt" value="filter" class="btn .btn-default">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="view">
        <a href="#" id="grid" class="switcher active"><i class="fa fa-th fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="grid-view"> Grid</span></a>
        <a href="#" id="list" class="switcher"><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="list-view"> list</span></a>
    </div>
        <hr id="hr-1" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="container blocks" id="content">
    <?php
    //Grab the variable sent through link by sub_category.php
    //session_start();
    $subcategory_id='';
    $subcategory_id= $_GET['sub_id'];
    $_SESSION['sub'] = $subcategory_id;
    $row_count = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['submitt'])){
    $city_id=$_POST['filter'];
        if($city_id == 'all'){
            $sql="SELECT * FROM tadd WHERE sub_id = '$subcategory_id' ORDER BY add_nm";
        }else{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM tadd WHERE sub_id = '$subcategory_id' AND c_id = '$city_id' ORDER BY add_nm";
        }
    }else{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM tadd WHERE sub_id = '$subcategory_id' ORDER BY add_nm";
    }
    //$sql="SELECT * FROM tadd WHERE sub_id = '$subcategory_id' AND c_id = '$city_id'";
    $conection = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($conection, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $name = $rows['add_nm']; 
        $add_id = $rows['add_id'];

        //get the join date and Expiry date to hide Expired Contents
        $current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); 
        $exp = strtotime($rows['exp_dt']); 
        $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($conection);
        //get Images
        //$shop_image = trim($add_id.'.jpg');
        ?>
            <!-- Do Not Show Expired Contents -->
            <?php if( $current_date <= $exp ) {?>
                <div class="dialog">
                    <div class="shop_img">
                        <img src="../image/shops/1.jpg" alt ="<?php echo $name;?>" >
                    </div>
                    <hr id="hr">
                    <div class="shop_name">
                        <?php echo strtoupper($name);?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="detail.php?add=<?php echo $add_id;?>"><div class="address">
                        <span id="1">ADDRESS</span><span id="2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></span>
                    </div></a>
                </div>
    <?php 
            }
        }
        if( $row_count == 0 ){
            echo '<div class ="msg">Sorry! No Entries Found.</div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
<?php
    include("../footer.html");
?>
</footer>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#city-filter").submit();
})
</script>
```

As i shown in image when user comes to this page it has to show only success classes. But it is showin all...when i hot filter it'll show currect.so i want to cancel hiting submit manually and auto submit the form

Comment: Why do you have ```<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#city-filter").submit();
})
</script>```? This is going to submit the form each time the page loads.

Comment: because you are submitting to same location... change your form action or simple track form submission in this page and do your business logic and redirect to new page.   name your form and check with if as if(isset($_post['myform']))

Comment: well that is i used for submit form on page load..which i got from other threads on stack overflow

Comment: just track your form submission with if condition whether you get a form post request or not and at the end of your process put die there which will not loop

Comment: what i found is it is not at all submitting..if i use action to different page it should go to that page if the form is automatically submitting..instead it remains of same page..but again when i hit the filter button it redirects..please check the image

Answer (score 2):

You could put it inside a condition to check if there are some `dialog` divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.dialog').length === 0 ){ // check the length of dialog div if 0
      $("#city-filter")[0].submit(); // then only submit the form
    }
})
```

Instead use the native `.submit()` event on the `form`.